# How do you do CSS unit math in javascript and retain the CSS unit?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a variable, radius that is set to '20%'. In my code, I want to set a height to twice the radius like -

```
height = radius * 2;
```

and I want it to work whether radius is '20%', or '20px', or '20em', or '20vw' and the result to be '40%', or '40px', or '40em', or '40vw' respectively.

(I am using Reactjs and have access to Radium)

Comment: Separate the number from the units, do the math, and then concatenate the original units back onto the result.

Comment: @Pointy that's my fallback solution. Was hoping there was a more elegant way.

Comment: or use a preprocessor and corresponding loader

Comment: what about `height = "calc(2*" + radius + ")"`

Comment: @wero - I like that approach. A little worried about using `calc` for generated content in legacy browsers.  I will do some tests and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse out the number with `parseFloat` and the rest of the string are the units:

```
var value = "123px";

var n = parseFloat(value);
var u = value.trim().substring(n.toString().length);

console.log("number:", n, "units:", u, "value:", n + u);
// Output: number: 123 units: px value: 123px
```

Or you could do it with regex (thanks **brendangibson** in comments):

```
var value = "123px";
var matched = value.match(/(\d+)([^\d]*)$/);
var num = matched[1], unit = matched[2];
```

And with a destructuring array assignment:

```
let [all, num, unit] = value.match(/(\d+)([^\d]*)$/);
```

Or you can use one of the many [JS libraries](https://github.com/heygrady/Units) to do it for you.

Comment: Try `value = " 123px"`. Converting to a number and then to a string is not an identity function, the space disappears. And then `substring` starts at wrong position.

Comment: @Oriol True, trim is needed to avoid that, but it would be pretty unusual to have leading whitespace like that... even if you set `style.left = "  123px"` the parsed value you get back is `"123px"`.

Comment: `const [all, value, unit] = length.toString().match(/(\d+)([^\d]*)$/);`

Comment: @brendangibson I think you meant `[all, num, unit] = value.match()`... ;) Nice regex, post an answer?